# Custom field permissions based on workflow or rule/action

Tags: 7, users, workflows

Is there a way to trigger permissions to specific fields in a content type based on a workflow or rule/action?

For example, for a content type called 'article':

- field 1 is writable, field2 is hidden
- workflow state has changed
- field 1 is now read-only and visible
- field 2 is now visible and writable

I came across this module called [Workflow Fields](http://drupal.org/project/workflow_fields) that sounds perfect, but it is only available for Drupal 6.

Comment: Workflow Fields is now available for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Rules module and custom fields to create triggers that changed when being passed from role to role.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields).

> Define dependencies between fields based on their states and values.
>
> Conditional Fields for Drupal 7 is an user interface to the new States API, plus the ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on certain conditions when viewing content.

Comment: I am all ready using the conditional fields.  The problem is changing the permissions on a given field once a workflow has been set.  I wish there was a rule or trigger that could do this, but I still cannot find anything like the workflow fields. :(